# Content caching on MacOS - Connected Clients

Tags: macos, mdm, ventura

I'm pretty new to MacOS and the world of Apple, so this might be an easy one. We have about 50 iPads in our school (with more certainly coming) which I manage through an MDM. Last week, to accelerate downloads and reduce bandwidth, I installed a new mac mini (running macos Ventura 13.0.1) and activated content caching. I can see in the activity monitor that content is served from the cache as I launched an iOS update for a few devices as a test.

However, I was wondering if there is a way to see which devices (IP and/or MAC Address, device type etc...) are currently using the content cache?

I cannot find any such command. The AssetCacheManagerUtil and AssetCacheLocatorUtil terminal commands do not seem to allow this.

Is there any way to get more info on the content cache usage?

Thanks

Kind regards

Gilles